# How to write a web application where updates by one user are immediately visible to all users?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I am trying to write a web application that displays to users a hierchical tree. Users can add,delete, and update the tree but the tree should look the same for all users. My first thought to save the state of the tree (i'm using JSON to represent the data in the tree) in a database but, what happens if there are a million/billion/etc number of people using the application? How do you make sure that all users are physically seeing the same thing if additions/updates/deletes could be going on simultaneously?

Comment: ask facebook, though I don't think they know the answer ...

Comment: Take a look into websockets. Google uses it for their game racer, shown here: https://www.chromeexperiments.com/experiment/racer. They showed off the sync between the devices at Google I/O 2014.

Comment: websockets i will definitely look into thanks @EthanBrouwer

Comment: Websockets is the nice and 'idealistic' way to do this but the best solution depends on just how 'realtime' updates need to be.  For example, if you can afford a ~200ms delay to the updates (which isn't really much) you could easily do this by polling the server with an ajax request and `setInteval`.  This is also a nice cross browser way to do it as websockets are a relatively new technology and would require a library (e.g. socket.io) to ensure the solution is cross platform and has a fallback.

Comment: a 200ms delay is definitely acceptable for this application

Answer (score 0):

Something like signalr would would help:

http://signalr.net/

> **What can you do with ASP.NET SignalR?** SignalR can be used to add any
>   sort of "real-time" web functionality to your ASP.NET application.
>   While chat is often used as an example, you can do a whole lot more.
>   Any time a user refreshes a web page to see new data, or the page
>   implements Ajax long polling to retrieve new data, is candidate for
>   using SignalR.
>
> It also enables completely new types of applications, that require
>   high frequency updates from the server, e.g. real-time gaming.